# How to merge a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Inbound table:

| Date | P_ID | S_ID | Measure1 | Measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-12 | 01 | 03 | 100 | NULL |
| 2022-02-12 | 01 | 03 | NULL | 200 |
| 2022-02-13 | 01 | 02 | 300 | NULL |
| 2022-02-13 | 01 | 02 | NULL | 400 |

There are some more measure fields in this table.
In each row is only one measure field <> NULL.

I want to transfer/merge this table into another one, which is empty at the beginning:

Outbound table

| Date | P_ID | S_ID | Measure1 | Measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-12 | 01 | 03 | 100 | 200 |
| 2022-02-13 | 01 | 02 | 300 | 400 |

I've tried that with merge:

```
MERGE @OutboundTable AS TARGET
USING @InboundTable AS SOURCE
        ON  TARGET.[Date]   = SOURCE.[Date] 
        AND TARGET.[P_ID]   = SOURCE.[P_ID]
        AND TARGET.[S_ID]   = SOURCE.[S_ID]
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
         TARGET.[Measure1] = ISNULL(SOURCE.[Measure1],TARGET.[Measure1]),
         TARGET.[Measure2] = ISNULL(SOURCE.[Measure2],TARGET.[Measure2])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
    (
          [Date]
        , [P_D]
        , [S_ID]
        , [Measure1]
        , [Measure2]
    )
    VALUES
    (
          SOURCE.[Date]
        , SOURCE.[P_ID]
        , SOURCE.[S_ID]
        , SOURCE.[Measure1]
        , SOURCE.[Measure2]
    )
    ;
```

But it did not work. The outbound table contained the same rows as the inbound table.

How can I perform this transformation?

Comment: A merge statement will never combine rows. You need to build your own query for that.

Comment: And a `MERGE` will not insert and update against the same source or target rows multiple times. If the target is empty you only need an `INSERT` anyway

Comment: is this a one time process or you will be doing repeating this process ?

Comment: @Squirrel: this process will be repeated every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Query:

```
INSERT INTO outbound (date, P_ID, S_ID, Measure1, Measure2)
SELECT date, P_ID, S_ID, MAX(Measure1) AS Measure1, MAX(Measure2) AS Measure2
  FROM inbound_table
  GROUP BY date, P_ID, S_ID;
```

Comment: Half a solution, but what about the merge?

Comment: Updated the solution!

Comment: That's not a merge, that's an insert.

Comment: @DaleK OP says that the target is empty anyway, so makes no difference. It was a mistake to use `MERGE` anyway

Comment: @charlieface, OP says the table *starts* off empty, not that it is always empty.

Comment: @DaleK, charlieface got my explanation right :) the outbound table will be truncated every time before loading. In that case, the suggested solution works fine. If the outbound table would not be emtpy, then I guess, I have to merge it after grouping.

Comment: @notna it's not a merge if the table is empty